# Adding an alpha channel performance

Tags: image, numpy, go

I'm looking to convert my array to a PNG image. It is currently an RGB8 encoded image. I can do so using the following code:

```
s2 := make([]uint8, 2048*2448*3)
err = dset.Read(&s2)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var (
    width  = 2048
    height = 2448
    rgb    = 3
)

to1D := func(x, y int) int {
    return (x * height * rgb) + (rgb * y)
}

img := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, width, height))
for ix := 0; ix < width; ix++ {
    for iy := 0; iy < height; iy++ {
        cords := to1D(ix, iy)
        img.SetRGBA(ix, iy, color.RGBA{R: s2[cords], G: s2[cords+1], B: s2[cords+2], A: 255})
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to add an alpha channel that doesn't involve looping through each pixel and setting it individually?

Thank you!

Comment: "Better" in what way?

Comment: The question has the `numpy` tag.  Does that mean you are also interested in a solution that uses Python+NumPy instead of go?

Comment: @Adrian perhaps using Golangs image/draw library if possible. This seems not the best on performance. Or maybe leverage multiprocesisng somehow?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser it's tagged like that because the input array is from a python numpy array. Wasnt sure if it mattered

Comment: @Chaos: you're basically writing directly to the underlying slice with `SetRGBA`, are you actually having a performance problem? You can just iterate over the image slice yourself if you want to avoid the function overhead (the offset calculation might be adding up).

Comment: @JimB It takes about 150ms to do this currently. For something like 60k images that would add up. So if there is a way to make it better that would be appreciated

Comment: @Chaos: as I mentioned, try iterating over the pixel data slice itself and see how much faster it is.

Comment: @JimB doing so doesn't make the calculation just go away, iterating the slice would require `ix` and `iy` to be calculated instead. There's probably nothing to be gained that way.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: you're probably right, and the calls should be getting inlined anyway since there's no interfaces involved at this level.

Comment: Just asking out of curiosity.  Does it matter, if you add the alpha?  Especially, if you just want it to be 255.  Won't most applications just default the alpha to 255?

Comment: @tobeypeters I don’t believe there is a way to save as a PNG without having an alpha channel because you can’t create an RGBA image in Golang.